# What does the BFF item do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I've gotten the BFF item a couple of times, but so far I haven't noticed any effects that I could attribute to it specifically. The description just says "Your friends rule," which isn't very helpful. So, what does it do?

Answer (score 4):

I know it makes your familiars bigger, which I assume also means they do more damage.  If you're curious for items in general, I would recommend looking the items up **[on this item database](http://platinumgod.co.uk/rebirth)**, as they have most of the items up there and will (hopefully) continue adding them.

Comment: The synergies section of that site at least is out of date for rebirth. For instance, it lists Spoon Bender as having no synergy with Brimstone, and my giant purple homing blood beams strongly disagree.

Comment: The synergies tab is for vanilla.  The rebirth tab is the one with info on rebirth items.